# What is the need of "onExtentHistoryChange" in map navigation toolbar

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In map navigation toolbar what is the need of "onExtentHistoryChange" in on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Navigation toolbar</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  @import "https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";

  .zoominIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_zoomin.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .zoomoutIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_zoomout.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .zoomfullextIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_fullextent.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .zoomprevIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_previous.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .zoomnextIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_next.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .panIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_pan.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .deactivateIcon {
    background-image: url(images/nav_decline.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
<script>
  var map;

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/toolbars/navigation",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/Toolbar",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
    function (Map, Navigation, on, parser, registry) {

      parser.parse();

      var navToolbar;

      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "satellite",
        center: [-56.953, 57.472],
        zoom: 3
      });

      navToolbar = new Navigation(map);
      on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

      registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
      });

      registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
      });

      registry.byId("zoomfullext").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();
      });

      registry.byId("zoomprev").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();
      });

      registry.byId("zoomnext").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();
      });

      registry.byId("pan").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.activate(Navigation.PAN);
      });

      registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function () {
        navToolbar.deactivate();
      });

      function extentHistoryChangeHandler () {
        registry.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
        registry.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
      }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
<div id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomin"  data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoominIcon'">Zoom In</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomout" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomoutIcon'">Zoom Out</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomfullext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomfullextIcon'">Full Extent</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomprev" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomprevIcon'">Prev Extent</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomnext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomnextIcon'">Next Extent</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="pan" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'panIcon'">Pan</div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="deactivate" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'deactivateIcon'">Deactivate</div>
</div>

<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:512px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "onExtentHistoryChange" is the event. The on() event listener is calling the extentHistoryChangeHandler() to update the status of zoomprev and zoomnext.

Comment: Here's a CodePen to see it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGyXQV

Answer (score 1):

The way to step through and debug this is:

```
on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);
```

This line states that when the navToolbar's [ExtentHistoryChange](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/navigation.html#event-extent-history-change) event fires, the code within `extentHistoryChangeHandler` should be run. Examining this code shows:

```
function extentHistoryChangeHandler () {
  registry.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
  registry.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
}
```

This states that the `disabled` property of the Zoom To Previous and Zoom To Next buttons should be set to `True` if `navToolbar.isFirstExtent()`, in other words 'if the current extent is also the first extent in the toolbar's history'.

This makes sense - the Zoom To Previous/Next buttons can't do anything if there is no Previous/Next extent. This behaviour is equivalent to what you'd see in your browser's Forward/Back buttons.